# Bigquery: 'Resources exceeded during query execution' when query is transformed to view

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a complex query that works fine taking about 35 seconds and processing 5.5GB.
I would like to transform this query in a view, however, I cannot run the view and get this error:

```
Resources exceeded during query execution: Not enough resources for query planning - too many subqueries or query is too complex.
```

I'm trying to add these information that I have for clients transactions and there locations.

```
    AVG(locations.latitude) as latitude_avg,
    AVG(locations.longitude) as longitude_avg,
    AVG(locations.speed) as speed_avg,
    MIN(risk_city.distance) as min_distance_to_risk_city,
FROM aggregation_features ag_f
LEFT join merchant_features mer_f on ag_f.merchant_id = mer_f.merchant_id
LEFT join customer_features cus_f on cus_f.transaction_id = ag_f.transaction_id
    LEFT join (
         SELECT ST_DISTANCE(ST_GEOGPOINT(AVG(locations_1.longitude), AVG(locations_1.latitude)), 
      ST_GEOGPOINT(bc.longitude, bc.latitude)) as distance, transaction_id,
      bc.longitude as city_longitude, bc.latitude as city_latitude
      FROM  customer_features as cus_f, UNNEST(cus_f.locations) as locations_1
      cross join risk_cities_geolocation as rc
      group by transaction_id, rc.longitude, rc.latitude 
      ) as risk_city on cus_f.transaction_id = risk_city.transaction_id
    , UNNEST(cus_f.locations) as locations
```

The `cross join` is done with a table with 150 registers. I need to calculate the distance to the closest of those cities.

Is there anything I could do other than rebuild the query?

Comment: You might want to include the actual query in this question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the query is really big and with very specific names for the company. The query is an aggregation of features. The view already exists and I'm including some geolocation information and measurements of distance.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I will show here the sub query that I'm trying to add.

Answer (score 1):

I think what's happening is that when you put it in a view, the query is not able to be optimized because the optimizer is not able to see the whole query.Perhaps take a look at the query stages when you run the query as a whole and rework the query to match those stages.

For example, you could try moving:

```
SELECT ST_DISTANCE(ST_GEOGPOINT(AVG(locations_1.longitude), AVG(locations_1.latitude)), 
      ST_GEOGPOINT(bc.longitude, bc.latitude)) as distance, transaction_id,
      bc.longitude as city_longitude, bc.latitude as city_latitude
      FROM  customer_features as cus_f, UNNEST(cus_f.locations) as locations_1
      cross join risk_cities_geolocation as rc
      group by transaction_id, rc.longitude, rc.latitude
```

into a WITH statement or its own view.

Comment: I tried that, without success.
I also created another view with only this calculation, the view alone works, but if I try to join it with the original view the same problem happens. 
We probably have to move this to dataflow solution.